# Unable to View Source of an XML file using IE7

Tags: xml, http, internet-explorer-7, http-headers

I am enhancing our web framework to use web services and one of features I would like is the ability to view XML that has been submitted. I am using our Java servlet to launch a popup and serve the XML and this works - in IE7 I get the expected behaviour when of a nicely formatted and folding view of the XML. The problem is if I select 'View Source' I get a popup saying "*The XML source file is unavailable for viewing*".

I've used Fiddler to inspect the response headers which I've provided below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2009 15:23:56 GMT
Server: Oracle Containers for J2EE
Content-Length: 7835
Set-Cookie: p_session_id=20DB84E0FB3AAE905A0A07C86AD61A1E; Path=/
Set-Cookie: field_set_F2K_iMm34HT1t=fsF2N_iMm34HT1t; Path=/eng8
Cache-Control: private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Tue, 08 Sep 2009 15:23:59 GMT
```

Can anyone explain the reason for the error? I have a feeling it might be to do with caching but I haven't been able to solve it yet. The XML is valid and well formed.

Comment: Can you share a .SAZ file (Fiddler File > Save > Session Archive) showing the traffic?  What is the title of the popup?  Is the page returned over HTTPS?  

Do you see the problem on both Vista and XP?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design:

[PRB: Browsing and Saving the Default MSXML XSL Stylesheet in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282127)