# Unable to View Source of an XML file using IE8

Tags: xml, http, internet-explorer-8

i have a web-page that returns `XML` **with** an `xsl` stylesheet transform, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl'?>
<MyData>
   ...
</MyData>
```

It properly displays the transformed XSL as HTML. But when i try to view the XML source, Internet Explorer gives me the error:

> The XML source file is unavailable for viewing

[Some](http://www.errorhelp.com/search/details/11656/the-xml-source-file-is-unavailable-for-viewing) people [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394682/unable-to-view-source-of-an-xml-file-using-ie7/1468948#1468948) that this behaviour is [by design](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282127).

But i can give you a site where the desired behaviour works perfectly ([Blizzards WoW Armory](http://www.wowarmory.com/)) (i.e. you **can** view the xml source):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/_layout/pageIndex.xsl"?>
<page globalSearch="1" lang="es_mx" requestUrl="/index.xml" type="front">
  <pageIndex>
    <related-info/>
  </pageIndex>
</page>
```

So the argument that "this behaviour is by design" is disproven by direct observation.

What is wrong with **my** XML, that the source XML cannot be shown?

---

### Leading you down the wrong path

Here is some supplemental information.

Http response headers from Blizzard's (working) site:

```
GET http://www.wowarmory.com/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 233

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/_layout/pageIndex.xsl"?><page globalSearch="1" lang="es_mx" requestUrl="/index.xml" type="front">
  <pageIndex>
    <related-info/>
  </pageIndex>
</page>
```

And here are the response headers from my (borken) xml:

```
GET http://www.example.com/default.ashx HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
...
Content-Length: 131974

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/css/homepage.xsl'?>
<MyData>
   ...
</MyData>
```

### See also

- [Viewing source in XML to XHTML transformation through XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527300/viewing-source-in-xml-to-xhtml-transformation-through-xsl)
- [Unable to View Source of an XML file using IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394682/unable-to-view-source-of-an-xml-file-using-ie7)
- [PRB: Browsing and Saving the Default MSXML XSL Stylesheet in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282127)

Comment: I do not know about the error, but for example(http://www.wowarmory.com/search.xml): Even though the file extension is .xml, the files is being served as `text/html`.

Comment: @digitalFresh The homepage is not `.xml`, nor is my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `no-cache` was turned on

### Long Version

i stumbled across a blog post from a guy having a similar problem:

- [Debugging the Internet Explorer View Source problem with Fiddler and fixing ASP.NET](http://www.lowtek.com/blog/2006/06/debugging-internet-explorer-view.html)

Using the automatic debugging feature of Fiddler (a feature i'd never used), he narrowed it down the presence of a particular entry in the response headers:

```
Vary: *
```

He didn't understand *why* this header is causing IE to break, but he was able to remove it, and it fixed his problem. i don't have the `vary: 0` header in my response, but it did give me a direction.

i was reading the documentation that deals with this option: [HttpCachePolicy.SetOmitVaryStar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setomitvarystar.aspx). One thing caught my eye:

> **Note**
>   The use of the vary:* header can disable all client caching.

And so i wondered if the reason that "the XML source isn't available for viewing" is that there's a policy in place forcing IE to delete the XML source as soon as it's done (i.e. don't cache it)

Following in this guy's footsteps, i dug out fiddler and turned on the *Automatic breakpoints after response* feature. Turns out you can then muck with the response headers, rearranging, adding, changing, deleting stuff.

### Original headers (fails)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jul 2010 02:53:35 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 134772
Via: 1.1 www.example.com

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
```

i noticed that my headers have entries relating to caching:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

perhaps if i remove those? i go into the spot in fiddler and manually delete those two lines, leaving:

### Remove cache control headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Jul 2010 02:55:06 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 134772
Via: 1.1 www.example.com

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
```

**Note:** The headers are not there by mistake, the content is always stale, and i **want** the client to refresh every time.

My initial solution fixes the problem, but introduces a new one - since the content **is** always stale. While i want **ie** to fetch every time, i don't really want it to delete its own local copy.

The line in the `ashx` that's giving me grief is:

```
//client don't cache it (it's too volatile)
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

which turns into:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Removing the line leaves Cacheability as its default (Private), giving the response value:

```
Cache-Control: private
```

This allows the client to cache the content, and i can view source in the browser.

Comment: So, it is realeated to cache headers like I said.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, it seems to be; in the way that the private cache doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this behavior. Check my XML/XSLT driven site http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar

With IE8, I can see the source and transformation result (Tools menu).

Could it be related to private cache?

Comment: Your page is `xhtml`, with a stylesheet; as opposed to arbitrary `xml` (i.e. it's still html, and the browser can treat look at it as such)

Comment: @Ian Boyd: Did you check the headers? IE doesn't handle 'xhtml'. What a send trough wire is `xml`. It is the transformation wich result in `xhtml`. If I was sending `html`, it would be no transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem this days in Internet Explorer 9 but using the compatibility view and the 7 and 8 versions it provides in the developer tools.

I had this in my `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400, no-store"
    Header set Pragma "cache"
    Header set Expires "Mon, 5 Aug 2013 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

changed the cache-control headers to store and now I can see the xml source of the file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400, store"
    Header set Pragma "cache"
    Header set Expires "Mon, 5 Aug 2013 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

I got this error trying to figure out why a page that looks ok  on every single browser in windows and linux didn't work in compatibility view or older versions of Explorer. That problem is still a mystery since the document and headers are set to utf-8. But that's another thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I changed the Response.ContentType to "text/xml" which was previously "application/xml". The "text/xml" format allows to "View Source".

[What's the difference between text/xml vs application/xml for webservice response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832357/whats-the-difference-between-text-xml-vs-application-xml-for-webservice-respons)